# VBA code calling a stored proc - display message box if no records returned

Tags: vba

I borrowed this code and it seems to work fine. However, I'd like for it to show a message if the stored proc returns no record? Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim property_id As Double

property_id = Sheets("Pro Forma Input").Range("AD3").Value

With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("MyDataConnection").OLEDBConnection
.CommandText = "EXEC dbo.my_stored_proc '" & property_id & "'"
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("MyDataConnection").Refresh

End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: That connection is attached to something (a querytable, a listobject, a pivottable). Check what data they have after the refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
property_id = Sheets("Pro Forma Input").Range("AD3").Value

If property_id = "" Then
    MsgBox "There is nothing here!"
Else
End If
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think he means if the SQL Stored Procedure returns no rows

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the other poster for the solution, for some reason his/her post was deleted.  Here's what I did in case someone else needs it.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("FirstKey_One_Pager_connection").OLEDBConnection
.CommandText = "EXEC dbo.usp_FirstKey_One_Pager '" & property_id & "'"
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("FirstKey_One_Pager_connection").Refresh

If Sheets("DataSource").Range("B9").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "No property found using the RR ID entered"
Else
End If
```